# How can i sync partial data between two database?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-sql

I have 1000 records in Firestore and I want to sync 100 records to a secondary database in real time.

So if there is any change in both sides [primary Firestore database or secondary database] the data has to be in-sync.

Primary database - Firestore

Secondary database - can be Firestore, Cloud SQL, MongoDB or anything inside GCP platform.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here? Also specifying a secondary database might help. It just seems like you are trying to keep a copy of your database somewhere as Firestore is also mentioned in your secondary list. How about using a [multi-region](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/locations) location for Firestore then?

Comment: imagine a website like gsmarena.com - a high traffic website
if its running from a primary database firestore
if they need to give an api endpoint for data feeders, everyone will hit the api and might slowdown the speed of the primary website

so, how to have a read-write replica of firestore for primary website and API endpoint
also any changes in both database should be in sync with each other